# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.logging.object.hpel.WsLogRecord

Tags: java, websphere-8, rad

When I try to execute my java program in `RAD 8`, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.logging.object.hpel.WsLogRecord
```

I am unable to find this above jar file, can someone please suggest where I can find `WsLogRecord` class file?

I am using `Websphere 8` server along with RAD 8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007312/where-can-i-find-com-ibm-ws-logging-object-hpel-wslogrecord The above link may help

Comment: Thanks, I have already gone through above link but I don't see any solution to this problem there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find com.ibm.ws.logging.object.hpel.WsLogRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007312/where-can-i-find-com-ibm-ws-logging-object-hpel-wslogrecord)